# Fast way to send POST requests

Tags: php, swift, http-post

Is there any faster way than others to send `POST` request from `Swift` to `PHP`? I am using for example the `Alamofire` package. Is there any way to make it faster? Or every way takes the same amount of time to send the `POST` request and the time depends on the Internet?

I am asking because I use in my application a searching function that searches through a web server and I compared it with a Facebook search on the same Internet connection and Facebook is much much faster.

Comment: Are you asking us how to speed up the internet?  You sound like one of my project managers...

Comment: Haha no! I am asking if there is any faster "function" to do it.

Comment: Comparing yourself to a big company like Facebook in terms of performance will only bring you frustration. You don't have the same resources as they do (server farms, engineers, caching systems, etc).

Comment: You are probably right. Does the web server play a key role?

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire is a wrapper library around the Foundation networking classes and methods.

While there is no way to "magically" speed up a network request, you could invoke the methods that Alamofire calls directly, such as [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) and take out the middle man.

Comment: Do you believe that there is a difference just because, for example the NSURLSession method is called through another function?

Comment: @user3882720 no, but "objectively" invoking the NSURLSession methods directly will be faster, even if it is by a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will test it to see the difference.